# Is there any way I can use Ubuntu 22.04 version in raspberry pi 5

Tags: ros

I have already bought a brand new raspberry pi 5 but cannot use any ubuntu versions other than 23.10. I need to install ros 2 in pi 5 but i can't do it with version 23.10. So is there any way i can use lower ubuntu versions on pi 5 or any way i can install ros 2 in version 23.10. Thanks

Comment: why not? https://lkseng.github.io/posts/2024/01/07/ros-2-humble-on-raspberrypi-5.html seems to claim ROS 2 on a PI5 using 23.10 is possible. The adviced method though is to use docker

Comment: to add to the comment by @Rinzwind [this Ubuntu resource](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi) also indicates you can install 23.10 on Raspberry Pi 5

Comment: @graham he also wants ROS2, that one checks on os version and only the source version skips that check without disabling a lot of other features that are wanted.

Comment: @Rinzwind clearly he's not thought it through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Ubuntu 22.04 does not support Raspberry Pi 5, and there are [no plans](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=359566#p2157713) to backport its support in 22.04.

However, you can run ROS2 by [manually adding its repository](https://lkseng.github.io/posts/2024/01/07/ros-2-humble-on-raspberrypi-5.html).

(Thanks to @Rinzwind for sharing the link)